# Magento 2.1: Unable to import production images using "additional_images" column

Tags: magento2, import, magento-2.1, products, product-images

According to Magento 2 dev guide on [importing product images](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-import-product-images.html), we should be able to add additional images to the column `additional_images` using full URLs.

However, when I created an import csv file with the following example:

> sku, additional_images
>
> ExistingProdSKU1, http://someexistingwebsite.com/existingimage.jpg

I got a validation error for `Column names: "additional_images " are invalid`. I did not have any issue with `base_image`, `small_image`, and `thumbnail_image`, though. Have there been any changes on how we can import additional images to existing products on the catalog? Note that I'm currently running Magento 2.1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there's an extra space after "additional_images " in your error.  Try removing the space and uplaoding again.

If you're still getting the error, make sure you save your CSV as MS-DOS, and convert it to UTF-8.

Make sure your additional images to /pub/media/import and try adding the additional_images with just the image name in your CSV file, like /existingimage.jpg

Comment: *face palms* that was the issue. Thank you for spotting that.

Answer (score 2):

I would add that image file names mustn't contain spaces and brackets ()